# How to swap rows in a 2D vector?

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, stl

I want to swap two rows in my 2D vector by entering the size of the vector, the vector elements and 2 integer numbers `r1` and `r2` representing the rows to be swapped. I really don't know if there is a pre-defined function to do so.

Input

```
3   3
 
84 87 78 

16 94 36 

87 93 50

1 2
```

The array after swapping 1st and 2nd rows:

```
16 94 36 

84 87 78 

87 93 50
```

Comment: If you have `vector<vector<int>> matrix` then it's as simple as `std::swap(matrix[r1], matrix[r2]);`

Comment: @acraig5075 can you tell me why my code is not working                                                            `          void interchange(vector<vector<int>> arr,int  r1 ,int r2 ,int arrRows , int arrColumns)
{
  swap(arr[r1], arr[r2]);
  for(int i = 0 ; i < arrRows ; i ++)
  {
    for(int j = 0 ; j < arrColumns ; j ++ )
        cout<<arr[i][j]<<"\t";
    cout<<endl;
    }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use std::swap(mat[r1-1], mat[r2-1]);

Comment: it is not working ```void interchange(vector<vector<int>> arr,int  r1 ,int r2 ,int arrRows , int arrColumns)
{
  std::swap(arr[r1-1], arr[r2-1]);
  for(int i = 0 ; i < arrRows ; i ++)
  {
    for(int j = 0 ; j < arrColumns ; j ++ )
        cout<<arr[i][j]<<"\t";
    cout<<endl;
    }
  
}```

Comment: Pass the matrix by reference, i.e., change the parameter part as `vector<vector<int>> &arr`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked but can I ask why the "-1" ?

Comment: I'm not sure about it at all!